# Accessing index from extension

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, backend, indexing, indexer

I've made an extension with a single adminhtml page, added an index table for it in the installer and added an indexing model to the extension's configuration.

How do I implement this model and access this index from my extension to add data to it?

Comment: Please add more information to your question. How did you develop your module and created the index for it ?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism I've added some more information. Do I need to add anything else?